# Writing a powershell class callable in powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Using Cmdlet, (and/or PSCmdlet), I can create

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommunications.Read, "Blah", SupportsShouldProcess = true)]
public class BlahBlah : PSCmdlet
{
  /// ...
}
```

Then, in powershell, I can then call the command

```
import-module .\Blah.dll -Verbose
Read-Blah
...
```

And everything is fine.

But I would like to create a *class* rather than a *function* so I can get an object and then use it in powershell

Something like

```
import-module .\Blah.dll -Verbose
$myClass = New-Object Blah
$myClass.Read
$myClass.Save -File x.txt
$myClass.BlahBlah
...
```

Can the above be done in C#? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import a class from a .NET assembly, you need to use `Add-Type`, and not `Import-Module`:

```
Add-Type -Path .\Blah.dll
```

At this point, all public classes defined in your assembly will be available from PowerShell.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but how to I create the class itself? The example I gave only creates a function, not a class.

Comment: @SimonGoodman: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking... when you talk about a "function" you mean your `BlahBlah` CmdLet class, right? If you want to create a class in C#, then you just need to declare a public class that does not inherit from CmdLet. Does this answer your question?

Comment: What I mean is when I create a function ``[Cmdlet(VerbsCommunications.Read, "Blah"...`` I will then be able to use it in powershell as ``Read-Blah`` but now I would like a class to be available, as in ``$myClass = New-Object Blah`` or are you saying that it will be available to powershell as long as it is public?

Comment: @SimonGoodman: if you import the dll with `Add-Type -Path`, all the public types will be available from PowerShell, yes.

Comment: Well I feel rather silly, so straightforward... I thought I needed to derive from some other cmdlet or something.